# Cannot make install libcurl on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: gcc, curl, ubuntu-make

I am attempting to install libcurl from source on an Ubuntu server, OS version 16.04.4 LTS.

I am using gcc 8.1. Here is the configuration script I used:
curl version:     7.61.1
1234
    Install prefix:   /mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1

```
Compiler:         gcc-8
SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,mbedtls,cyassl,axtls,winssl,darwinssl} )
SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
zlib support:     enabled
brotli support:   no      (--with-brotli)
GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
resolver:         POSIX threaded
IPv6 support:     enabled
Unix sockets support: enabled
IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn2,winidn})
Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=no
Built-in manual:  enabled --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
ca cert bundle:   no
ca cert path:
ca fallback:
LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
RTSP support:     enabled
RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)
HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP GOPHER HTTP IMAP POP3 RTSP SMTP TELNET TFTP
```

Calling `make` works without incident, and `make test` likewise is OK. However, when I attempt `make install`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/install: 'system.h' and '/mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1/include/cu    rl/system.h' are the same file
Makefile:459: recipe for target 'install-pkgincludeHEADERS' failed
make[6]: *** [install-pkgincludeHEADERS] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving   directory '/mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1/include/curl'
Makefile:579: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[5]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1/include/curl'
Makefile:456: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[4]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1/include'
Makefile:1450: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[3]: *** [install-data-hook] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1'
Makefile:1280: recipe for target 'install-data-am' failed
make[2]: *** [install-data-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1'
Makefile:1234: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving   directory '/mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1'
Makefile:927: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving  directory '/mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1'
Makefile:1280: recipe for target 'install-data-am' failed
make[2]: *** [install-data-am] Error 2
```

Needless to say, I'm confused. The error 1 isn't very helpful coming from make, as it means the target needs to be remade - but it's failing and the target doesn't need to be remade AFAIK. I expect later errors are artifacts.

How do I debug this? Any hints would be welcome.

Comment: Did you set the install prefix to be the build directory?

Comment: I believe I did.

Comment: Having some difficulty with formatting...                                                                 
            `root@hpcDHCPPXE1:/mnt/share/codes/IFS/buildcurl/curl-7.61.1# prefix=``pwd``     CC="gcc-8" CFLAGS="-O3 -march=znver1 -I/usr/include/zlib-1.2.11 " LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib"  ./configure --prefix=`pwd` --disable-static --enable-threaded-resolver --with-zlib --with-ca-path=/etc/ssl/certs`

Comment: To be clear, the error occurs at make install. Make and make test compile fine.

Comment: Of course, it builds fine. `make install` copies the files from the build directory to the install prefix, so essentially you told it to copy each file to itself. That's why it's complaining.

Comment: Well when you put it that way... :-) I guess I assumed it was OK, because we're just creating libraries, so I thought that installation would be a matter of creating some .a files and the like and placing them where I said. But if the solution is to say -prefix=/usr/lib or whatever, then great. I'll try that.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having a similar issue, would be good to see your solution if you managed to find one